# Azure Search Service - Import from SQL Server on Azure VM failing ('Data source payload should specify at least one of datasource name and type)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sql-server

I'm attempting to add a new data source from a SQL Server on Azure VM for a search service and indexer I'm creating through the Azure web portal.  It's my understanding that I can create an index, import this data, then create an indexer to regularly push data to the index.  I'm adding the connection string for our SQL Server and getting a successful message when clicking "Test Connection".  The tables show up in a drop-down list, and I select one.

When I click "OK" on creating the new data source, a popup comes up that says "Sampling Data Source..." then an "Error detecting index schema from data source: 'Data source payload should specify at least one of datasource name and type'".

I've tried Googling this error, and I can't find anything on it and not sure how to fix it so I can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Azure Search portal support for SQL Server data sources. 
We'll investigate. In the meantime, you can create your datasource programmatically as shown in [Connecting Azure SQL Database to Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers).

Comment: Is there any fix to this or anything I can do, and what exactly is the error trying to tell me?  I was hoping to use the Azure online portal rather than writing custom code or making API calls just to set up the index/indexer.

Comment: We are looking at this. Also saw your other more conceptual question on indexers and added a couple of useful links there.

Comment: Hi @Andy, we've found and fixed the issue in our dev branch. This will be rolled out in production next time we deploy our portal code, probably next week. Thanks for reporting this!